# Dropdown list in bottom navigation using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to display a horizontal list by clicking on one of the `BottomNavigationBarItem` buttons? What I want is that if the `Clothes` tab is clicked by the user, the list of clothes will appeared as demonstrated in the picture below.

[image]

This is my existing code

```
final List<Widget> _widgets = <Widget>[
  ClothesPage(),
  ColorsPage(),
  IdeasPage(),
  ProfilePage(),
];

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;

    return Scaffold(
      // This body is new.
      body: _widgets[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: colorScheme.onSurface.withOpacity(.40),
        selectedLabelStyle: textTheme.caption,
        unselectedLabelStyle: textTheme.caption,
        onTap: (value) {
          _currentIndex = value;
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: true,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  _widgets[_currentIndex],
                  SizedBox(
                    // Use whatever height you desire.
                    height: 90,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Clothes'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.design_services_rounded),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Colors'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.colorize_rounded),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Ideas'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline_rounded),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Profile'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.face_rounded),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ClothesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Card(
      elevation: 9.0,
      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
      child: new Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(
                'assets/shirt/white-shirt1.jpg'), // Use the path here.
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColorsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          "Color",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IdeasPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          "Idea",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          "Profile",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any dropdown list in your example. Do you mean the horizontal list displaying your clothing products? In that case, you can include a `ListView` with `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` at the bottom of your `ClothesPage`

Comment: `Do you mean the horizontal list displaying your clothing products?` exaclty !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `showDialog` is unnecessary when you have the `_widgets[_currentIndex]` as your `Scaffold`'s body. You can do this:

1. Remove the `showDialog` within the `onTap` property of the `BottomNavigationBar` & use `setState()`:

```dart
BottomNavigationBar(

// ... other lines

onTap: (value) {
   // This notify the widget to rebuild, without it the screen will not react to your gesture
   setState(() { 
     _currentIndex = value;
   });  
},
)
```

2. Add the `ListView` within your `ClothesPage`. Full working code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: SomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomeScreenState createState() => _SomeScreenState();
}

class _SomeScreenState extends State<SomeScreen> {
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _widgets = <Widget>[
    ClothesPage(),
    Container(),
    Container(),
    Container(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // This body is new.
      body: _widgets[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        onTap: (value) {
          // This notify the widget to rebuild, without it the screen will not react to your gesture
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = value;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Clothes'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.design_services_rounded),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Colors'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.colorize_rounded),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Ideas'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline_rounded),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text('Profile'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.face_rounded),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ClothesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: new Card(
            elevation: 9.0,
            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
            child: new Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(
                      'assets/shirt/white-shirt1.jpg'), // Use the path here.
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 150,
          child: ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    width: 150, //! Modify the width of each item
                    child:
                        Container(), //! Add your clothing product photos here
                  ),
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
              itemCount: 5), // Number of your clothing products
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Back, thanks for answering this question, i copy your code and remove unnecessary thing, but when i click the `Clothes in bottom navigation` nothing happen

Comment: @Rene sorry for late reply, I've update the full working code. Please check! The Clothes tab should be navigated to when click on the Clothes button